# how to change a string to Date format?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

This might be a duplicate somewhere, but I have a simple df:

```
df1_schema = StructType([StructField("Date", StringType(), True) ])
df_data = [('1-Jun-20',)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(df_data)
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_data, df1_schema)
#df1 = df1.withColumn("Date",to_date("Date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
df1.show()

+--------+
|    Date|
+--------+
|1-Jun-20|
+--------+
```

I tried to change to Date format but it just gives me a null value.
This is what I tried:

```
df1= df1.withColumn("Date2", F.to_date(col('Date'), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
+----------+-----+
|      Date|Date2|
+----------+-----+
|1-Jun-20  | null|
+----------+-----+
```

any solution to this?.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for your `Date` is `"d-MMM-yy"`

```
df1.withColumn("Date2", F.to_date(col('Date'), "d-MMM-yy")).show()
+--------+----------+
|    Date|     Date2|
+--------+----------+
|1-Jun-20|2020-06-01|
+--------+----------+
```

This also works for `01-Jun-20` or `10-Jun-20`.